# Get the product price from a element JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a script to make some calculation but i dont know
how to get price from a element check the code below

```css
/* THE PRICE DOESNT SHOW ON THIS SNIPPET BECAUSE REQUIRES TO BE IN SAME DIRECTORY WITH FILE */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
        <label for="qty_product">qty</label>
          <input type="number" value="0.01" class="qty" id="qty_product"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
        <label for="price_product">price</label>
          <input type="number" readonly value="0" id="price_product"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="row my-4">
        <div class="col-9 text-right total">
         Total
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-2 total-val">
          <span id="total_value">0</span
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>

<script>
    function calculateTotal()
{
  let unit_price={
    <!-- the price should be always * 100 -->
    product: 304.36 * 100  
  };
  let item_price={}
  
  item_price.product = ($("#qty_product").val() * unit_price.product )
  $("#price_product").val(item_price.product); 
  
  let total = item_price.product;

 
  $("#total_value").text(total);
  
}

$(function()
 {
    $(".qty").on("change keyup",calculateTotal)
})


</script>

<!-- I WANT THE PRICE TO COME FROM THIS ELEMENT NOT FROM ONE IN THE SCRIPT* -->
<stock-market-widget type="inline" template="generic" assets="MSFT" markup="{price}" api="yf"></stock-market-widget>
<!-- I WANT THE PRICE TO COME FROM THIS ELEMENT -->

<script>
var premiumStockMarketWidgets = {
  pluginUrl: '../',
  assetsLogoImages: JSON.parse('<?php print json_encode($assetsLogoImages)?>')
}
</script>
<script src="../assets/dist/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the pcice to come from **stock-market-widget**,
and always go * 100, i dont tried any way by id or class because im a beginner on this
javascript and stuff!! i will be thankful if someone helps !!!
Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 1):

add a more attribute in value

```
<stock-market-widget type="inline" template="generic" assets="MSFT" value="{price}"  markup="{price}" api="yf"></stock-market-widget>


<script>

var stockprice =$('stock-market-widget').val();
//now put variable stockprice where you require

</script>
```